# How do you convert iframe to encoded javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to convert iframe scr into encoded javascript so the the user can't find the real url when viewing in page source. Or if anyone knows the source to this script
http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/iframe-encoder/
since that site is what I'm looking for but I don't know the source code to it

Comment: *"so the the user can't find the real url"* - Regardless of what obfuscation you might make in your code, if the user's browser is making a request to this URL then the user can see this URL.  The code obfuscation only makes it more difficult for you to support and maintain the code, it does nothing to prevent the user from seeing the request.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=hide+iframe+url+from+user+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<***

Comment: Look in the network tab here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/952svdnm/ - it is showing the link completely clearly

Answer (score 0):

The attached website uses this two functions :

```
function TextEscape(os)
{
    var ns = '', chr = '', cc = '', tn = '';
    var t;

    for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        tn = i.toString(16);
        if(tn.length < 2)tn = "0" + tn;
        cc+=tn;
        chr+=unescape('%'+tn);
    }

    cc=cc.toUpperCase();
    os.replace(String.fromCharCode(13)+'',"%13");

    for(q=0; q<os.length; q++)
    {
        t = os.substr(q,1);
        
            for(i=0; i<chr.length; i++)
            {
                if(t == chr.substr(i,1))
                {
                    t = t.replace(chr.substr(i,1),"%"+cc.substr(i*2,2));
                    i = chr.length;
                }
            }

        ns+=t;
    }

    return ns;
}


function TextEncode(txt)
{
    var txtEscape = TextEscape(document.cipher.decode.value);

    txtEscape = txtEscape.replace(/%/g,'@');

    document.cipher.encode.value = "<script type='text/javascript'> str='" + txtEscape + "'; document.write(unescape(str.replace(/@/g,'%'))); <\/script>";
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/952svdnm/